# CSS 100vh responsive issue

Tags: html, css

I created this css snippet.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}

.container__img {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">HEADER</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__inner">
    <div class="container__img">
      HELLO
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/30/01/05/milky-way-2695569__340.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I set 100vh to have the page 100% of page height, but appears the next issue when i resize the page vertically:
[image]

How you can see the image goes over the header, but it should stop when is near header like:
[image]
Question: Why it is happening and how to solve this?

Comment: @ShounakDas, why? this is a good practice to set the height of the page. Could you explain? And what your comment has related to my question?

Comment: @ShounakDas, you say that `height: calc(100vh - 50px);` is not correct?  https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-calc-in-css/

Comment: you can subtract it in calc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc()

Comment: Only IE and Opera mini doesn't support calc. So you can used it.

Comment: @Shounak Das, this is not my question.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a habit for yourself to wrap all the divas in the `main` div:

```
<div class="main">
...
</div>
```

When this `main` div is absent in the structure of html, then problems may arise in the future.

I made some changes to the `css`. If you have any questions, then ask me.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  flex: auto;
}

.container__img {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="header">HEADER</div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container__inner">
      <div class="container__img">
        HELLO
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/30/01/05/milky-way-2695569__340.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: a small addition: it's a bit better to inherit border-box instead of setting it for each element https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Answer (score 0):

When you resize the page vertically, the image goes over the header because the div "container__inner" and the div "container__img" have `height: auto` (by default). That means their height will be equal to the maximum height of the elements inside (here is the img).

To solve this problem, you just need to set `height: 100%` for one of them. Then its height will not exceed the height of the parent element (the div "container")

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  flex: auto;
}

.container__img {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
 text-align: center;
}

.header {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="header">HEADER</div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container__inner">
      <div class="container__img">
        HELLO
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/30/01/05/milky-way-2695569__340.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please avoid code-only answers. The question explicitly asks "Why it is happening" and you don't address that at all.